# how do I save flask app logs separately per day instead of one giant file

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a python flask app running on EC2.
To enable UI interface to be functional, I run this on ec2 after logging in as the correct user:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:application  -z 120 --http-timeout 120 --enable-threads -H /home/test/env --daemonize /home/test/test.log
```

and the UI becomes operational. When i click the download button certain computations take place before the csv becomes ready to download. I don't have a uwsgi.ini file or any kind of nginx.

After a point the test.log becomes a very large file;
How do I write log files so that each days log gets written to a separate file?
or what is the best way to prevent one large log file from getting generated and instead have something that is more manageable?

Answer (score 2):

Uses the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` class.

The `TimedRotatingFileHandler` object will create a log file for each day, but you will have to handle it within the server application code

```
import os
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from datetime import datetime


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(os.path.join('./', 'custom_log.log'), 
                        when='midnight', backupCount=7)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("Info")
logger.warning("Warning")
logger.error("Error")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement log rotation using Python logging handlers:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = RotatingFileHandler('test.log', maxBytes=12000, backupCount=5)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    app.run()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler

This would rollover the logs when the `maxBytes` size has been reached. The primary log file will remain `test.log` but the filled log will be renamed to `test.log.1`, `test.log.2` and so on.